# Circuitikz & op amp: different symbols for input and output

Tags: circuitikz, opamp

This is from `texdoc circuitikz`:

```
If you want different symbols for input and output you can use a null symbol and put them manually using the border anchors.

\begin{circuitikz}[]
\ctikzset{amplifiers/plus={}}
\ctikzset{amplifiers/minus={}}
\draw (0,0) node[fd op amp](A){};
\node [font=\small\bfseries, right] at(A.bin up) {1};
\node [font=\small\bfseries, right] at(A.bin down) {2};
\node [font=\small\bfseries, below] at(A.bout up) {3};
\node [font=\small\bfseries, above] at(A.bout down) {4};
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

I want to use this feature in `op amp`, so I changed `fd op amp` to `op amp`

But this gives an error:

```
Package PGF Math: Unknown function `out' (in 'bout up').
```

How can I use different symbols for input and output in `op amp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal op amps have just one output, so it breaks when you ask for a non-existing anchor. So you can use the same trick but the anchor for the output is a plain `bout`:

```latex
\documentclass[border=2.72mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[]
    \ctikzset{amplifiers/plus={}}
    \ctikzset{amplifiers/minus={}}
    \draw (0,0) node[op amp](A){};
    \node [font=\small\bfseries, right] at(A.bin up) {1};
    \node [font=\small\bfseries, right] at(A.bin down) {2};
    \node [font=\small\bfseries, left=6pt] at(A.bout) {3};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edited from @Rmano

```
\documentclass[border=2.72mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[]
    \ctikzset{amplifiers/plus={}}
    \ctikzset{amplifiers/minus={}}
    \draw (0,0) node[op amp](A){};
    \node [font=\small\bfseries, right=10pt] at(A.-) {1};
    \node [font=\small\bfseries, right=10pt] at(A.+) {2};
    \node [font=\small\bfseries, left=15pt] at(A.out) {3};
    \node [font=\small\bfseries, below] at(A.up) {4};
    \node [font=\small\bfseries, above] at(A.down) {5};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]